# Multiple session IDs being set with domain in Spring Webflux

Tags: java, cookies, session-cookies, spring-webflux

In Spring Webflux, I want to add the root domain attribute (Eg: example.com) to my cookies so that the same session can be used for sub-domains as well.

I've followed the tutorial [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/boot-webflux-custom-cookie.html#webflux-custom-cookie-sample) to set the domain attribute in the cookie by defining a custom `WebSessionIdResolver` bean. Unfortunately, after I login, all subsequent HTTP requests send multiple session IDs in the Cookie header. This causes the Spring server to fail to recognize the correct session ID of the logged in user.

Sample code:

```
    @Bean
    public WebSessionIdResolver webSessionIdResolver() {
        CookieWebSessionIdResolver resolver = new CookieWebSessionIdResolver();
        resolver.setCookieMaxAge(Duration.of(30, DAYS));
        resolver.addCookieInitializer((builder) -> builder.domain("example.com"));
        resolver.addCookieInitializer((builder) -> builder.path("/"));
        resolver.addCookieInitializer((builder) -> builder.sameSite("Lax"));
        return resolver;
    }
```

Response header for `/login`:

```
set-cookie:
    SESSION=b86789ea-7cdd-4e66-910f-7788dad2c0ce; Path=/; Domain=example.com; Max-Age=2592000; Expires=Sat, 28 Aug 2021 08:08:26 GMT; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
```

Request header for subsequent HTTP requests:

```
Cookie: SESSION=257d34e5-7264-4cc0-b98e-7adcfde216b3; SESSION=b86789ea-7cdd-4e66-910f-7788dad2c0ce
```

Any help on how do I solve this problem would be appreciated.